# How to dynamically add and remove tabs from TabView?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to develop a little app in NativeScript with Angular. I used a TabView with a component for each Tab. At first i used the Angular directive (*ngIf) to control the visibility of these tabs:

```
<TabView (selectedIndexChanged)="onSelectedIndexChanged($event)">
   <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Kezdőlap'}">
      <Home></Home>
   </StackLayout>
   <ng-container *ngIf="loginService.isAuthorized">
      <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Hírek'}">
         <News></News>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Csomagok'}">
         <Packages></Packages>
      </StackLayout>
      <ng-container *ngIf="loginService.loggedInUser.role == Role.Admin">
         <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Felhasználók'}">
            <Users></Users>
         </StackLayout>
      </ng-container>
   </ng-container>
</TabView>
```

First, this *isAuthorized* variable is false and when I change it to true, all of the Tabs appear. BUT after I change back the *isAuthorized* value to false, i got an error:

**Error: View not added to this instance. View: CommentNode(51) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: TabView(424)**

After a little Google, I found this [BugReport](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/621) and in it stated that I cannot remove Tabs with Angular directives only rebind all of the Tabs programatically.

And here comes my problem. I don't know, how to instantiate an Angular component (Home, News, Package, Users) which can be inserted into a StackLayout programatically.

Comment: how about you create 2 tabviews ? one for loggedin users and one for not loggedin ? then use ngIf on `TabView` itself. Or better use `[visibility]="yourcondition ? "visible" : 'collapse'"`

Comment: In the end I used an another TabView as you suggested, but I totally forgot the `[visibility]` property... Thanks for the help.

Comment: i am glad it worked :)